# Would it be possible to create a Chromebook extension that would toggle the "Configure IP address automatically" network setting on and off?

Tags: networking, chromebook

Chromebooks at a certain facility will not work with static IPs, and they have reserved IP addresses, but for some odd reason they will not grab those from the DCHP server. By toggling Configure IP address automatically off for a few seconds and back on, the Chromebook gets its reserved IP and works fine. In about 6-8 months we will be changing the entire network and resolving this issue, but in the meantime if I could create a shortcut method for the end users to be able to do this easily it would be a big stone out of my shoe...

Comment: This isn't Programming Related question, Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten I posted this. In order to resolve the issue, I did use "code" and "programming" to create a script that would do what I described above. So, it wasn't a networking question, it was a programming question.